# Shift in image caused by refraction in normal image formation and shift in fringe (youngs double slit experiment)

Tags: optics, refraction, double-slit-experiment

for shift in a image from its original position due to a slab of thickness $t$ and refractive index $u$ is given by  $shift(s)=t[1-1/u]$

[image: shift(s)=t[1-1/u]]

and for shift in fringes formed during youngs double slit experiment, the shift is given by
$s=[u-1]tD/d$

where $d$ is fringe distance, $D$ is distance between fringes and sheet.

[image: shift due to slab inserted in youngs double slit experiment]

$D/d$ is constant, and the only changing factor is $t[u-1]$, bright fringe can be considered as an object so the above mentioned formula $t[1-1/u]$ should be applicable for fringes also. But the formulae obvious differ by a product of $u$.

why is the change in perceived image different in both cases? and what is the significance of this difference?